# how "intercept" messagebox & modify its content, and back to normal flow?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bunch of messageboxes in an existing app, both simple informations to user and also questions.

I would like to "intercept" them (for sure not the correct IT wording), change automatically its content, and then normally display it to user.
The "OK" or other standard return should be returned/forwarded to the initial messagebox.

The modification function is a kind of translation, but for the purpose of demonstration, lets say that this special function does += " AAA" to the content and += " BBB" to the top header.

> Note1: while searching, I have seen several custom message boxes, but
>   these are additional controls, mainly for changing the button captions
>   or style, not to "intercept". Please correct.
>
> Note2: fully agree that a better & cleaner MVVM structure would have avoided the
>   trick needed above, but this big app started some time ago, with a
>   very small and different aim

Comment: would the "-1" author be so kind to explain why negative ? maybe is the question not at his/her expertise level ?l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the code uses System.Windows.MessageBox.Show calls using text and caption arguments, you can try defining a public static MessageBox class in a common namespace of your application providing a similar Show method that updates the arguments and calls the original MessageBox.Show method, e.g.:

```
public static class MessageBox
{
    public static void Show(string text, string caption)
    {
        text += "AAA";
        caption += "BBB";
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(text, caption);
    }
}
```

Note: this will only work if you are able to rebuild the solution from source code, as it requires adding a new source code file (the custom MessageBox class), and then rebuilding the solution.

Comment: How is this different from going through each instance of `MessageBox.Show();` and changing that string directly? OP will have to go through them all either way to make this work.

Comment: If your app is under namespace X and your MessageBox class is also under namespace X, then all existing source code lines like MessageBox.Show("...", "...") will be routed through your class rather than calling the System.Windows.MessageBox. (I just tested.) So you don't need to update anything else in existing code.

Of course, this assumes you can rebuild the app from source code.

Comment: It also assumes that OP wants to add the exact same text to every MessageBox, which likely isn't the case as they say that its meant to be for translation.

Comment: Edit this answer and mention that this will work if OP is planning to refactor code. It's the only way this answer could help the OP, I think.

Comment: You can modify the logic in the custom MessageBox.Show method to actually call a localization service; the example was just like requested in your original question.

Comment: I updated the original answer and included a note referring the assumption of being able to rebuild the app from source code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible. You cannot have a reference to a MessageBox, so you cannot access it in any way once it is open.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx):

> You cannot create a new instance of the MessageBox class. To display a message box, call the static method MessageBox.Show.

This means that you cannot do like the following:

```
var box = new MessageBox([stuff]);
```

MS deliberately made the constructor or constructors of that class private (or protected), to make you use the factory method instead (`MessageBox.Show();`). Note that since they are explicitly defined, just not accessible, this means that no implicit constructor is generated either.

Doing this also won't work:

```
var box = MessageBox.Show([stuff]);
```

The `Show` method doesn't return a reference to the open box itself, but to the [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) object after it closes.

As for your situation, the only ways I can think of to solve your problem would be to either go through the program and change the strings, or create a new custom control and ditch the MessageBox entirely. You may be able to find another way, however "intercepting" the MessageBox instances isn't possible.

Comment: is it not possible just before it opens ? or by redesigning/completing the normal messagebox.show ?

Comment: In that case you might as well modify the string that gets passed to it. It isn't intercepting it though, its creating it the way you wanted it in the first place. To be clear, I assume "just before it opens" means right before you call `MessageBox.Show();`. You cannot call it and then stop its execution right before it shows the actual box and modify the text there.

Comment: no, you're right when it say "before it's opening", it is indeed after the call (otherwise i would replace by a completely other Windows functions, but I have too much of these now)

Comment: Sounds like the only way for the asker to solve this is via refactoring the application.